# Is an anti-pattern returning undefined or null inside componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: reactjs

1. Is an anti-pattern returning undefined inside componentWillReceiveProps?

Example:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.somethingHappened) {
       return
    }
    otherThingHappened()
  }
}
```

2. Is an anti-pattern returning null inside componentWillReceiveProps?

Example:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.somethingHappened) {
       return null
    }
    otherThingHappened()
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel like they're both fine since you'll want to do that fairly often, like when you receive props but don't want to update if one of them is the same as the previous ones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not. According to the [Component Specs and Lifecycle doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) `componentWillReceiveProps` is not expected to return anything at all. It seems weird though to return a value that will be discarded right afterwards.

Comment: So option 1: not returning anything at all, is slightly better than returning `null`. BTW I would not consider either of them "antipattern" in any case. My association with anti-pattern is "something that goes against the logical flow of the code". This question is related what to return, if anything. Neither option changes the flow of executing `componentWillReceiveProps` and then returning control back to React lifecycle.

Comment: An use case would be to exit early, example:

`if (!this.isAuthorized(nextProps)) {
  return
}
nextProps.showNotification(...)`

Comment: @HélitonNordt Exiting early is not a react-specific thing. See [should-i-return-from-a-function-early question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)  on programmers.stackexchange.com for pros and cons.

Comment: @Li0liQ I know it's not React specific, I don't said that. What I meant to ask is if it is ok to use early exiting in component life cycles.